# sddm service failed to start simple desktop display manager

Tags: boot, arch-linux, manjaro

I'm newbie in manjaro linux.
 After upgrade my system can't boot and stuck on starting version 231. 
I check my system with systemctl --failed and I found that sddm.service failed. 
I check sddm service with systemctl status sddm.service. and the result is:
 'failed to start simple desktop display manager' and
 when I try with sudo usr/bin/sddm it shows 
/usr/bin/sddm: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory 
what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It was related to qt5-base-5.7.0-7 so I downgrade to qt5-base-5.7.0-6 and solved.